# How Puma allows IO waiting to be done in parallel to improve MRI's throughput?

Tags: ruby, blocking, puma, gil, mri

From [Puma's README](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/README.md):

> On MRI, there is a Global VM Lock (GVL) that ensures only one thread can run Ruby code at a time. But if you're doing a lot of blocking IO (such as HTTP calls to external APIs like Twitter), Puma still improves MRI's throughput by allowing IO waiting to be done in parallel.

Unfortunately, it does not explain the mechanism of improving MRI's throughput.

I know that [MRI would release the GIL when calling system IO](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/05313c9/io.c#L1136), but it is the improvement by MIR instead of Puma.

I wonder how Puma improves blocking IO in parallel.

Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Puma (like iodine) offers a hybrid concurrency model of threads and processes. This means that once Ruby releases the GIL, another worker thread from the server's thread pool can process HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

Puma is using the [reactor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern).  Since [Puma 4.0.0](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/v5.1.1/History.md#400--2019-06-25), Puma is using [nio4r](https://github.com/socketry/nio4r) for the event handling, which means it can utilize native backends like [epoll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll) and [kqueue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue) (via [libev](https://github.com/enki/libev)). (On JRuby, nio4r supports [java.nio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_%28Java%29)).

Answer (score 0):

Nate Berkopec gave [a presentation on Puma in RubyConf 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4X_oBuPmTM), and he also wrote an [article](https://www.speedshop.co/2020/05/11/the-ruby-gvl-and-scaling.html) explaining the multi-threads helping explain this reason.

In short, the GVL will be released when there is one blocking IO. So, other threads could take the GVL and can process other requests.

As for the `reactor` in Puma, it's simply for buffering the requests, and only completed requests are sent to threads. In the behind, the `reactor` uses `nio4r`.